Dear PyGUI <built-in function add_static_texture> returned a result with an exception set
enter image description here
Problem:
I'm coding a movie search program. I'm having trouble displaying the poster when clicking on any genre.
Python Exception message:
Error loading texture for poster/155.jpg: <built-in function 
add_static_texture> returned a result with an exception set

Attempted Solutions
I tried removing:
posterImg = dpg.add_static_texture(width2, height2, data2, 
                                   parent="Genresults_list")
dpg.add_image(poster_path, width2, 
              height2,parent="Genresults_list")

and I realized there seems to be an issue with loading the image. Before posting here, I tried loading the image in a different context and it worked fine (meaning the image file exists and is not corrupted).
This is my first time using Dear PyGUI, so there's a lot I'm still unsure about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code:
def genre_menu_callback(sender, app_data, user_data):
    genre = user_data
    movies = fbg.find_top_movies_by_genre(genre.lower())  # Get movie list

    if not dpg.does_item_exist("Genresults_list"):
        print("Error: 'Genresults_list' does not exist!")
        return

    dpg.delete_item("Genresults_list", children_only=True)  # Clear old results

    if movies:
        row_counter = 0  
        current_row = None  
        for movie in movies:
            poster_path = f"poster/{movie['id']}.jpg"
            if os.path.exists(poster_path):
                try:
                    width2, height2, channels2, data2 = dpg.load_image(poster_path)
                    # Create static texture
                    posterImg = dpg.add_static_texture(width2, height2, data2, parent="Genresults_list")
                    dpg.add_image(poster_path, width2, height2,parent="Genresults_list")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error loading texture for {poster_path}: {e}")
                    posterImg = None
            else:
                print(f"Poster file not found: {poster_path}")
                posterImg = None

            # Start a new row if needed
            if row_counter == 0:
                try:
                    current_row = dpg.group(horizontal=True, horizontal_spacing=30, parent="Genresults_list")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error creating new row: {e}")
                    current_row = None

            # Add movie details
            if current_row:
                try:
                    with dpg.group(parent=current_row):
                        if posterImg:
                            dpg.add_image(posterImg, width=100, height=150)
                        title_movie = dpg.add_text(f"{movie['title']}", wrap=120)
                        dpg.bind_item_font(title_movie, movieText)

                        title_vote = dpg.add_text(f"{movie['vote_average']} ★")
                        dpg.bind_item_font(title_vote, movieText)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error adding movie details for {movie['title']}: {e}")

            row_counter += 1
            if row_counter >= 5:  # Reset for a new row
                row_counter = 0
    else:
        dpg.add_text(f"Không tìm thấy phim nào trong thể loại '{genre}'", parent="Genresults_list")

    switch_ui("Primary Window", "Genre UI")


You may want to try to explicitly assign your arguments (especially width and height) when you call dpg.add_image(). The method has several parameters and if you don't explicitly assign them -- using the syntax method_name(param_name = argument_value) -- it will assign them in the order they are declared in the method's definition. I do this with all of my DPG method calls to avoid assignment issues. See dearpygui.dearpygui.add_image() docs here.

Also, try loading all of your poster/<id>.jpg image files. You may find that only certain files cause errors, which will help narrow down your issue and supply us with more information. More context is always better when posting here.

Dear PyGUI accept various file types for its function load_image but for JPEG it has a limitation of "no 12-bit-per-channel JPEG OR JPEG with arithmetic coding". Ensure the JPG complies with that. You could try to convert the JPG to PNG for example and see if it loads.
